# How to share Image to a specific user of Facebook messenger and Whatsapp

Tags: android, facebook, whatsapp

I already implemented how to share image in Facebook and WhatsApp messenger. But i wanted it in different way.

## code

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager =(ActivityManager)c.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20){
    mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(0).processName;
    //Toast.makeText(this,mPackageName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    mPackageName = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).baseActivity.getPackageName();
}

Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg"); 
shareIntent.setPackage(mPackageName);

shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(dataFile));

Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via");
new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 


c.getApplicationContext().startActivity(new_intent);
```

It simply share image according to the package name. But the problem is it asks me to again choose the user from the friend list to share the image. But i want to share the image to the specific user from the beginning. I don't want it to redefine the user again.

Is there is a way to do it? in application like Facebook messenger and WhatsApp

This is a custom keyboard application where i am sharing the image to the application in where my keyboard is opened currently.

Answer (score 2):

At least for Facebook Messenger; no, this is not possible. It is designed in such a way that you, as a developer, can notify the app that you want to share something. But the user will always have the final control to select the audience.

The best way to integrate with Messenger is to use the [Send Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android).

I believe this is also the case for Whatsapp, but I'm not 100% sure about that. Perhaps somebody else can confirm that.

Comment: ya i also tried to find any information about it and even facebook messenger sdk doc didn't give me much